# Need a way to unplug the device from PC?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

How to unplug the device from pc? I'm always stop the adb from my TaskManager after only i can unplug my device from PC. In that time i'm having some errors in my Eclipse :

```
[2011-09-16 12:05:14 - Logcat]An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:395)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:284)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel$3.run(LogPanel.java:527)

[2011-09-16 12:05:14 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly     closed by the remote host
[2011-09-16 12:05:16 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1
[2011-09-16 12:05:18 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 2
[2011-09-16 12:05:20 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 3
[2011-09-16 12:05:22 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 4
[2011-09-16 12:05:24 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 5
[2011-09-16 12:05:26 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 6
[2011-09-16 12:05:28 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 7
[2011-09-16 12:05:30 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 8
[2011-09-16 12:05:32 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 9
[2011-09-16 12:05:34 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 10
[2011-09-16 12:05:36 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 11
```

What's the way to avoid this attempts and how to unplug safely without stop adb?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this app, promises adb over wifi.

http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/use-adb-wirelessly-over-wi-fi-with-adbwireless-for-android/